# How to export customer data programatically?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, export

I need to export customer data programatically once in a day. I'm using php script to write the export functionality. I used,

```
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
```

to get Orders export functionality.

How can I write a script to export customer data?

Comment: Joey, i gotta ask, why do you want to do it programmatically? Magento already gives you the option to export both customer main file and just customer addresses. Just wondering if there's any particular reason as to why you're doing it programmatically

Comment: yes, it's for usage for external program and I need to only include only requested fields and use xml format as output

Comment: Ah gotcha, fair play, i was maybe thinking you wanted the data and decided to do it programmatically.

Comment: I'm too lazy for that anyways ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')->create()->getCollection();
```